# What is the correct way to avoid c++ compiler's warning?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

How can I remove annoying warning "non-void function does not return a value in all control paths"?

There are some explanation of my code:

1. Poll two sockets.
2. a) If there any data on transport socket -> recv and return message from function
   b) If there any data on inproc socket -> recv and forward message from inproc socket to transport socket and continue to poll.

```cpp
std::optional<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > pizza::transport::SharedAsyncPoller::receive()
{
    // poll both sockets and return if there
    while (m_poller.poll())
    {
        // if any data appears on transport socket
        if (m_poller.has_input(m_transportSocket))
        {
            zmqpp::message msg;
            m_transportSocket.receive(msg);
            if (msg.parts() < 2)
                return std::nullopt;
            else
                return std::make_pair(msg.get(0), msg.get(1));
        }
        // or if there any data on inproc socket
        if (m_poller.has_input(m_inprocSocket))
        {
            zmqpp::message msg;
            m_inprocSocket.receive(msg);
            m_transportSocket.send(msg);
            // it is okay that we do not return anything
            // we just forward the message from inproc to transport socket
            // and continue to poll sockets
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `return std::nullopt` after that while loop.

Comment: You may put `throw` in the unreachable function end. It suppresses warnings too.

Comment: ... and what is the function supposed to return when `m_poller.poll()` is false? Add that return statement, and program is fixed.

Comment: @nada thank you, that solved the problem !

Comment: @eerorika ye, I forgot about it, thanks for the hint

Comment: @exoze You're welcome. That is a very valid warning btw. Always watch out that your function returns in all its possible outcomes, else there be dragons. _Compiler warnings are meant to be helpful messages to us programmers._ Don't turn them off.

Comment: @nada, ye, I try to avoid warnings as much as possible, this was the only warning in the whole project, i was inattentive btw. Thanks again !

Comment: The correct way is to ensure that all possible execution paths through the function reach a valid `return` statement, without ambiguity that may confuse a compiler.  In your code, consider what happens if `m_poller.poll()` returns a false (or non-zero) value - in that case, your function drops off the end (without a `return` statement).

Answer (score 1):

From the code, warning is legit.

when `m_poller.poll()` returns `false`, function reach end of non-void function without return.

So you have to `return` (or `throw` or call a no-return function as `abort`) after the loop.

if `m_poller.poll()` cannot return false (due to a hidden dependency),
you might rewrite your loop (and so avoid unneeded condition)

```
while (true) {
    m_poller.poll();
// ...
}
```